# IOS - bit rate file video hls

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

I get bit rate file video hls from server, using MPMoviePlayer, MPMovieAccessLogEvent, I calculate by:

```
double bitrate = 8 * event.observedBitrate /1024;
NLog(@"%f",bitrate) -> 19697.920189
```

This is bitrate from .m3u8 play media downloaded, I think, but I don't know the number very big compare number of the file .m3u8 (in fact m3u8 have three bit rate "400kb, 800kb, 1.5mb")

Can guide me get bit rate right from .m3u8.

Answer (score 1):

That is the observed bit-rate for downloading the media, and not the bit-rate of the media content. The documentation for `observedBitrate` has this to say:

> The empirical throughput across all media downloaded. Measured in bits

There is a problem with your calculation.

```
8 * event.observedBitrate / 1024
```

because `(event.observedBitrate / 1024)` gets us the value in kilo-bits per second. If you want that to be in kilo-bytes per second, then you need to divide it again by `8` instead of multiplying by `8`. If the calculations were right, you will get `307.78` kilo-bytes per second instead which seems like a reasonable download speed.

Comment: is it possible to get the file name which is currently playing according to the bit rate?

Comment: @Anurag: Can you please guide for using HLS in iOS? I am implementing in one of my project but it is giving me an issue that sometimes audio continues to play and video stops.  Do we need to switch the URL stream based on observedBitrate?

Comment: @anurag: Could you please join this discussion over http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82452/hls-in-ios?

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora - Could you post your issue as a new question on StackOverflow? You are more likely to get the issue resolved faster like that. If you're using AVPlayer for HLS playback on iOS, and have set up the HLS files correctly, then AVPlayer will adjust the stream quality based on current network conditions.

Comment: @Anurag: I have already posted issue. I have spent n number of days to get any workaround this as well. Please see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289200/unable-to-get-tracks-of-avasset-using-hls-while-retrieveing-bitrate