# Unable to get tracks of AVAsset using HLS while retrieveing bitrate

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am using HLS streaming in my application and I am using AVPlayer.
Now I want to get bitrate of the video track using AVAsset. Although I have added observer and other stuff I am getting tracks array as empty always.Am I on right track or missing anything?

Answer (score 6):

HLS is adaptive, therefore, bitrate can vary across the duration of the stream based on various conditions. You are on completely the wrong track, unlike playing a file, either local or from a network URL, currentItem.asset.tracks will always be nil.

You'll need to query the AVPlayer's currentItem's accessLog and inspect the appropriate "events".

The following from the documentation should give you the information you need;

Look at ;

[AVPlayerItemAccessLog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemAccessLog_Class/index.html)

and

[AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent)

**EDIT:**

You might benefit from reading apple's [Live streaming overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/StreamingMediaGuide.pdf) 
this will give you a better understanding of the .m3u8 index files, specifically that the media file can be encoded for various bit rates to accommodate different network throughput/congestion. The client is responsible for switching between segments encoded at different bit rates.

The observedMinBitrate and observedMaxBitrate are likely to be the properties you'll find most useful, however withought knowing your intended use, it's hart to say if any will suffice. Keep in mind also, as per the Docs, these are Per Segment (refer to the overview for a better understanding of segment).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. After reading given links I am having one doubt, do I need to consider indicatedbirate property as current bitrate? Also after reading it's explanation I am confused that whether it is my current network bitrate(bandwidth) or not?

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora - `indicatedBitrate` is the bitrate required for the stream that is currently playing. It is not the network bandwidth. You can get the network bandwidth using the `observed<Max|Min>Bitrate` methods.

Comment: @Anurag: Thanks for your reply. I am using AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntryNotification to get changed observed<Max|Min>Bitrate but it always returns me -1 for this even though I switch the network it show me -1. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

An `AVPlayerItem` has a `tracks` property, which is an array of `AVPlayerItemTrack`s. These probably represent the current tracks that are loaded in the `AVPlayerItem`. They will change as playback progresses and can be observed via KVO. An `AVPlayerItemTrack` has an `assetTrack` property referencing an `AVAssetTrack`. Video, audio, closed captions, and all variants of those will appear as independent tracks. Their types can be inspected via their `mediaType` property if you're only interested in video -- though you may be interested in all enabled tracks. An `AVAssetTrack` has an `estimatedDataRate` which may be what you're looking for.

You can find sparse documentation of these classes and properties by drilling down from [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/).